# Powershell file splitting

Tags: powershell

I want to split a large file with Powershell which contains many blocks into several files where each file has 1 block and each file would get a file name out of a certain word that is located in that block. Each block consists of: start header, text in the file and end footer.

**Example of  a file:**

```
--start--
Text in a file that contains word "aaa"
--end--
--start--
Text in a file that contains word "bbb"
--end--
--start--
Text in a file that contains word "ccc"
--end--
```

**Result after split:**

File: `aaa.txt` with content:

```
--start--
Text in a file that contains word "aaa"
--end--
```

File: `bbb.txt` with content:

```
--start--
Text in a file that contains word "bbb"
--end--
```

file: `ccc.txt` with content:

```
--start--
Text in a file that contains word "ccc"
--end--
```

Comment: Do you have a *question*? SO is not a script writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I am putting this here, since it too long for the comment section:

There is a whole article series on this topic, with samples:

- [Splitting Large Files in Smaller Parts (Part 1)](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/splitting-large-files-in-smaller-parts-part-1)
- [Splitting    Large Files in Smaller Parts (Part 2)](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/splitting-large-files-in-smaller-parts-part-2)
- [Splitting Large Files in    Smaller Parts (Part 3)](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/splitting-large-files-in-smaller-parts-part-3)

These articles point to a module in the MS powershellgallery.com one can leverage as well.

```
 Find-Module -Name '*splitter*'

Version              Name                                Repository           Description
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------
1.3                  FileSplitter                        PSGallery            provides PowerShell commands to split a file in multiple parts, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`switch -file`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) as follows:

```
switch -file large.txt {
  '--start--' { $header = $_; continue }
  '--end--'   { $footer = $_; , $header + $content + $footer > $outFile; continue }
  default     { $content = $_; $outFile = ($_ -split '"')[1] + '.txt' }
}
```

Note: The above assumes that there's exactly 1 content line between the header and footer lines; a bit more work is needed to handle multiple content lines.